# Created a custom button component but I can't get it to appear disabled

Tags: react-native

I am creating a custom button on react native and trying to have it appear as disabled (by lowering the opacity) if the credentials are bad or upon loading.

I have the component working correctly but it won't lower the opacity

I have played around with the values but nothing seems to take, I'm new to this so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

This is my button

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import colors from "../config/colors";

export default class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        label: "",
        disabled: true
      }
  }

  render (){
    const { disabled, label, onPress } = this.props;
    const containerStyle = [
      styles.container,
      disabled ? styles.containerDisabled : styles.containerEnabled
    ];
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.container}
        onPress={onPress}
        disabled={disabled}
      >
        <Text style={styles.text}>{label}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: colors.BLUE,
    marginBottom: 12,
    paddingVertical: 12,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)",
  },
  containerEnabled: {
    opacity: 1
  },
  containerDisabled: {
    opacity: 0.3
  },
  text: {
    color: colors.WHITE,
    textAlign: "center",
    height: 20
  }
});
```

It appears with opacity:1 even though I meant for it to be 0.3 from the beginning.

On my app.js I call it by doing

```
constructor(props){
     super(props);

     this.state = {
       email: "",
       password: "",
       emailTouched: false,
       passwordTouched: false
     }

...

render() {
    const {
      email,
      password,
      emailTouched,
      passwordTouched
    } = this.state;

...

<Button
            label={strings.LOGIN}
            onPress={this.handleLoginPress}
            disabled={!email || !password}
          />
```

Comment: I don't see you use containerStyle,

Comment: @cuongtd wow I can't believe I missed that, thanks! Can you make it an answer so I can choose it as the right one?

Comment: nevermind, I'm happy to help

Answer (score 0):

In your render method - you don't have any prop of disabled, rather use  const {disabled} = this.state. that should work

Comment: you mean in here? 

render (){
    const { disabled, label, onPress } = this.props;
    const containerStyle = [
      styles.container,
      disabled ? styles.containerDisabled : styles.containerEnabled
    ];

Comment: Exactly. .  use render (){ const { disabled, label } = this.state; instead